# AngularJS directive controller resolve interpolated attributes?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I just think the way I'm doing this sucks, and I'd like to know if there is a better way?
Here's the directive:

```
<myDirective myAttribute="{{val}}"></myDirective>
```

Here's the directive's controller:

```
.controller('myDirective', ['$scope', '$attrs', function ($scope, $attrs) {
    $attrs.$observe('my-attribute', function (x) {
        $scope.myAttribute = x; // yay we finally have the interpolated value...
    });
```

This sucks for a number of reasons I don't want to get into.  Is there a way to ensure that interpolated values are resolved before controller is called?

Ideally the $scope.myAttribute would have the interpolated value when the controller initializer is called.

EDIT: My primary goal is to get rid of the dependency on $attrs that this controller has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular 1.2 RC2 or maybe RC3 broke a few things with attribute interpolation. See this bug I filed:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4525

Which just got fixed today. You should **never** see double curly braces in your value, that's a bug.

However, as soon as an attribute is found to use interpolation, it's evaluation becomes asynchronous. Even with this bug fixed, you should see it's synchronous value as `undefined` (i.e. if you just read the value right out of $attrs). That's why you have to $observe, so the value gets handed to you as soon as it's available.

As to why it can't be available right away, it's dynamic. The evaluation of `{{val}}` might be different all the time. That's just the nature of Angular, everything live updates all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the best way is:

```
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        attrs.$observe('myAttribute', function(x) {
            scope.setMyAttribute(x);
        });
    }
```

And then:

```
.controller('myDirective', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.setMyAttribute = function (x) {
    $scope.myAttribute = x; // yay we finally have the interpolated value...
});
```

**EDIT: It took some doing... and here is a plunker demonstrating this bug:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/p46zuYbFAFCYH394zrUY?p=preview

Note the importance of using "templateUrl" in the child directive.  Using just "template" and the bug disappears.

Comment: Except for some strange reason the $observe in the link function is returning x = {{val}} rather than the interpolated val.  Any help?

Comment: It seems that attrs is not the same as $attrs.

Comment: I read the source code and attrs is the same as $attrs.  I have no idea why moving attrs.$observe() call into the link function makes it so interpolation fails and the value of x is always {{val}} rather than the interpolated value of val.

Comment: Could you please reproduce the error you get with x = {{val}} in this plunker? http://plnkr.co/edit/crWZqBOY8eVBz4IggQBX?p=preview